# Error при расширении класса

Tags: swift4

Есть расширение класса:

```
extension Array{
    mutating func shuffle(){
        let count = 52
        for i in 0..<(count){
            let j = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(count - i))) + i
            if (i < j){
                (self[i], self[j]) = (self[j], self[i])
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Также объявлен массив `var tab = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]`. Функцию `shuffle` я вызываю следующим образом:

```
print("Shuffle array 1 : \(tab.shuffle)")
```

Всё компилируется, но если я вызываю метод, то выскакивает такая ошибка:

> error: partial application of 'mutating' method is not allowed

Подскажите, как мне решить данную проблему?

Comment: А Вас не смущает то, что код из Вашего вопроса падает почти при каждом запуске?

Answer (score -1):

Первое: при вставки кода на форум пропустил скобки `print("Shuffle array 2 : \(tt.shuffle())")`

Второе: я хотел вывести информацию при том что метод ничего не возвращает

Comment: Чтобы дополнить свой вопрос, просим вас воспользоваться опцией редактирования. Кнопку «Опубликовать ответ» следует использовать только для исчерпывающих ответов на вопросы. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/353675)

Comment: @Dmitriy указанная в вопросе ошибка возникает при попытке вызова `shuffle` без скобок, я думаю это и было описано в ответе.

Comment: @RomanPodymov А у него в ответе написано "при вставки кода на форум пропустил скобки", к тому же даже с учетом вашего примечания мне, например, все еще непонятно, это уже ответ или дополнение к вопросу.